# Flatten nested list that has floats in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 nested lists like the following and i'm trying to flatten them so i am able to plot the data:

```
List1 = [[[2189.369140625]], [[2715.13818359375]], ... , [[2810.3173828125]]]
List2 = [[3372.06005859375], [3376.110107421875], ... , [3344.18994140625]]
```

I tried using list comprehensions like this:

```
List2 = [item for sublist in List2 for item in sublist]
```

But it returns this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: there is probably one regular list in **List1**, and when you try to iterate over it you get the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: No i tried it but it returns the float object is not iterable error.

Comment: Yes it worked!!!! Thank you!